# Fix the following lines in your .forceignore and add '# .forceignore v2' to your .forceignore file to switch to the new behavior

Tags: salesforcedx, vs-code

I have the following `.forceignore` file:

```
# List files or directories below to ignore them when running force:source:push, force:source:pull, and force:source:status
# More information: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_exclude_source.htm
#

package.xml
Marketing_Cloud

# LWC configuration files
**/jsconfig.json
**/.eslintrc.json

# LWC Jest
**/__tests__/**
```

The only line I've added was:

```
Marketing_Cloud
```

And when I run command:

```
sfdx force:source:status
```

I get error message:

> === Source Status
> No results found
> (node:22676) Warning: The .forceignore file doesn't adhere to .gitignore format which will be
> the default behavior starting in Spring '21 release. More information on .gitignore format here: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore. Fix the following lines in your .forceignore and add '# .forceignore v2' to your .forceignore file to switch to the new behavior.
> (node:22676) Warning:   Marketing_Cloud

Base on Mohith Shrivastava advice, I've updated my `.forceignore` file to:

```
# List files or directories below to ignore them when running force:source:push, force:source:pull, and force:source:status
# More information: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_exclude_source.htm

# .forceignore v2

**/Marketing_Cloud.namedCredential-meta.xml
**/Marketing_Cloud.authProvider-meta.xml
**/namedCredentials/Marketing_Cloud.namedCredential-meta.xml
**/authproviders/Marketing_Cloud.authProvider-meta.xml
**/namedCredentials/**
**/authProviders/**
**/flows/**

package.xml

# LWC configuration files
**/jsconfig.json
**/.eslintrc.json

# LWC Jest
**/__tests__/**
```

And yet still `force:source:status` returns the files I am trying to ignore.

**Questions**

1. What is wrong with the line I've added?
2. What should I do to fix my `.forceignore` file?

Comment: what specific files or folders are you intending to forceignore by your “Marketing_Cloud” line? Thanks for the info

Comment: Hi @PeterNoges - `Marketing_Cloud` is actually a `Named Credential` and an `Auth. Provider`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the warning says, your `.forceignore` file is not adhering to the `.gitignore` [format](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore).

The recent release of CLI recommends (for now it's a warning but looks like from Spring 21 that's the expected format) that you keep your `.forceignore` following the [standards](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) similar `.gitignore`.

This is documented [here](https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/blob/main/releasenotes/README.md#5020-october-22-2020---cli-7771)

So you will need to do the below changes so in any folder if it finds Marketing_Cloud it's ignored

```
# .forceignore v2

**/Marketing_Cloud.namedCredential-meta.xml
Marketing_Cloud.namedCredential
```

The last one is for pull so it makes sure you don't sync these to your local

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118254/discussion-between-mohith-shrivastava-and-phil-w).